# How can i display the right numbers in my counting

Tags: javascript, math

I want to count down a counter. However, it always starts one number later. I know the problem, but I can't find the solution.

```
function countStart() {
    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
        time -= 1;
        document.getElementById('counter').textContent = time;
        if (time < 1) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

If I count down from 10. If it starts at 9, how do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decreasing your "time" variable before you display it. So if your "time" variable has a value of 10 initially, it will get reduced to 9 before being displayed due to the statement "time -=1" occuring before setting it as textContent for your element (and thus displaying it).

Try decreasing your "time" variable after setting it as textContent of your counter element.

```
function countStart() {
  const countdown = setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementById('counter').textContent = time;
      time -= 1;
      if (time < 1) {
          clearInterval(countdown);
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just put `time-=1` below the line where you change `DOM`

```
function countStart(time) {
    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
        //document.getElementById('counter').textContent = time;
        console.log(time)
        time -= 1;
        if (time < 1) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

just changed dom manipulation to `console.log`